# Where exactly is this building located in Cuba?

Tags: where-on-earth, cuba, architecture, locate-this

I'm preparing our next trip to Cuba and seeing some pictures, I've found [this one](http://comerviajaramar.com/2015/04/02/5-fotografos-que-nos-muestran-la-verdadera-cuba-en-80-fotos/#jp-carousel-54071):

[image]

I suppose it's located in Havana, but cannot find where exactly (address or GPS location). The most significant feature is the ants in his facade. Does anybody know where it is?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Google reverse image search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?hl=en) locates [the original of this picture](http://avaxnews.net/fact/Gigantis_in_Contemporary_Art.html). It is the [Fausto Theatre in Havana](http://cubaabsolutely.com/content/fachada-del-teatro-fausto/). The ants were a temporary exhibit.

Answer (score 20):

That is the [Teatro Fausto](http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/20795), on the corner of Prado and Colon, in Havana Cuba. The "ants" you see in the photo were [an artist's exhibit in 2012 for the Havana Biennial](http://www.artsobserver.com/2012/06/19/havana-biennial-at-a-major-theater-ants-courtesy-the-artist/). [They are no longer on the building.](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ruamps/2692805350/)

Answer (score 11):

It's the Fausto Theater, as identified on this [photo blog](http://pixtale.net/2012/05/photos-of-2012-week-20/).

[More information on the history of the theatre found on cinematreasures.org](http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/20795).

> Located in the Habana Vieja (old town) district of Havana, on the
>   Prado at the corner of Esquina Colon in the Jaruco neighborhood.
>
> The Cine-Teatro Fausto was built in 1938 and designed in an Art Deco
>   style, by architect Saturino Parajon. It has a simple Art deco facade,
>   with vertical patterns above the entrance, flanked by horizontal
>   delineations and has curved corners. Decorative botanical friezes and
>   reliefs suggesting castlations on top.

And a [Google maps link](http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/20795/map) for the location.